# Can't figure out how to override associations in FactoryGirl and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Given this factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory:prospect do
        account
    end
end
```

where "account" points to a valid Factory (and works fine), I can't figure out how to override the account in my test.

I've tried this:

```
account = FactoryGirl.create( :account )
prospect = FactoryGirl.create( :prospect, account: account )
expect( prospect.account ).to eq account
```

But it doesn't, I get two separate account objects. Any idea (a) why this is happening and/or (b) how to override the account creation in the spec test?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and I get a green dot.

Do you have

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
  end
end
```

and everything correctly set up in your models and database?

Comment: Yes. I can create an account, a prospect, and all works fine. It's when I try to override the account that's defined in the prospect factory association that things go pear-shaped.